# Django nested models in class based views

Tags: python, django

I'm relatively new to python/django and I'm not sure I'm doing this right

Suppose there are 2 different apps `projects` and `items`. The url I have in the `items` app is:

`path('projects/<slug:project_slug>/items/', ItemListView.as_view())`

And the cb-view:

```
class ItemListView(CanViewProjectMixin, ListView):
    model = Item

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.project = Project.objects.get(slug=kwargs.get('project_slug'))
        return super(ItemListView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(ItemListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['project'] = self.project
        return context
```

This seems to work fine in the view, and it is passing the `project` object to the template via `context`

However, I'm not able to get `self.project` in the `CanViewProjectMixin.dispatch()` method.

Any help would be appreciated

**Update**

`CanViewProjectMixin` has a `get_permission_object()` method which retrieves the `project` object in the main project app views where `project` is retrieved via default `get_object()`  or via `self.project` where the view is a child of `project` like in the example above.

```
def get_permission_object(self):
    if hasattr(self, 'project'):
        return self.project
    return (hasattr(self, 'get_object') and self.get_object() or
            getattr(self, 'object', None))

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_permission_object()
    ...
    # do stuff with the object and return super()
```

On project views where `project` is retrieved via `get_object()` it works just fine, the problem is only on child views

Comment: `get` method runs after `dispatch`. If think you should attach `self.project` in dispatch if you need it there too.

Comment: Could you provide your class `CanViewProjectMixin` ?

Comment: Did u confirmed that get is called before dispatch? Normally dispatch is called before get, so self.project is not assigned yet in dispatch.

Comment: As the previous comments have noted, `ItemListView` defines `self.project` in the `get` method. That's too late if you want to use it in `dispatch`. You need to define `self.project` in `dispatch` (Django < 2.2) or `setup` as in my answer (Django >= 2.2).

Answer (score 1):

The recently released Django 2.2 includes a new `setup` method which is called by the view before calling `dispatch`. This is the best place to initialize new view instance variables like `self.project`, without having to override `dispatch`.

```
class ItemListView(CanViewProjectMixin, ListView):
model = Item

def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    super().setup(request, *args, **kwargs)
    self.project = Project.objects.get(slug=kwargs.get('project_slug'))

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['project'] = self.project
    return context
```

As the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.setup) point out, you must always call `super()` when you override `setup`.